# HTML not rendering correctly

Tags: html, css, rendering

I am following Ruby tutorial to make a Sample App. I made the signup page but the errors in signing up are being rendered in a funny way. The period at the end of the error line comes before it. And also the asterisk and bullet point are on the wrong end of the line.

Here is the page source HTML source:

```
<div class="container">
            <h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="UPwVQbjK5hdjlsXerJfnAESR61pKf3l/K1u2/05+ILY=" /></div>
                <div id="error explanation">
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            The form contains 2 errors.
        </div>
        <ul>
                <li>* Password doesn't match confirmation</li>
                <li>* Email is invalid</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

This the CSS:

```
#error_explanation {
    color: #f00;
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 0 18px 0;
    }
}
```

Also I would like to mention, the input field also had a similar problem where the input cursor was on the right end of the box (like arabic text). I solved that one by adding the `direction: ltr;` line in my input textarea css:

```
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    direction: ltr;
    @include box_sizing;
}
```

I treid adding the direction styleing in my css but that didn't work. I can't think of anything else. Please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: There's a space in `<div id="error explanation">`, try changing it to `error_explanation` so the CSS that removes the list style matches it.

Comment: Also the fact that the cursor was at the end suggests you have `direction: rtl` or the `dir="rtl"` attribute set on one of the parent elements which would explain why the list is displaying the bullets right aligned.

Comment: @Sam Turns out none of the parent tags had dir set to rtl but I had a default plugin for rtl languages enabled, I deleted it but that didn't work too. But I tried both your solutions, they worked. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So even though the things suggested by @Sam worked, I found the same problem in other places on the site. I fixed most of them using direction: ltr. Later when I deployed to Heroku, lot of things failed. When I looked for the solution for that I found I need to pre compile my assets before deploying to Heroku. I am using bootstrap.

Surprisingly `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` solved the problem on localhost as well as Heroku.

So yeah, problem was in the asset pipeline compilation.